Dynamic JSON Equivalent for Flutter's Visibility Widget
In Flutter, we use the Visibility widget to control the visibility of a child widget. What is the equivalent approach to achieve the same functionality when building widgets dynamically from JSON?
I didn't find any such JSON file in this link.
https://pub.dev/packages/json_dynamic_widget

You can use Json's Key to reflect the dynamic widgets. The package you have mentioned don't have this Visibility widget .

What are you trying to achieve? Is it Server Side Rendering?

There are two answers.  The first is the Visibility widget is now included with the newly released 7.3.1 version.  However, the second is "you can add any widget you want".  The documentation describes how to build your own custom widgets so if there are widgets you need in the future, you can always add them to your own code base and run the code generator to "JSON-ify" them.
https://github.com/peiffer-innovations/json_dynamic_widget/tree/main/json_dynamic_widget#creating-custom-widgets
